# Should a noun following "singular they" be singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, singular-they

I've understood how to use singular they on a single sentence, but the problem comes with articulated sentences like this one:

> If a person lies to you this way, they are probably thieves.

My doubt is about its correctness, I would also say it this way:

> If a person lies to you this way, they are probably a thief.

Is the second sentence correct?

Comment: If you use the singular *they*, and add in the dropped *way*, the second sentence is correct.

Comment: First, almost nobody would say "they are" -- it's contracted to _they're_ most of the time. Second, predicate count nouns with an indefinite subject are normally singular, with an indefinite article, **unless** the speaker wishes to emphasize the non-singularity of the subject. This is definitely not the case with [singular _they_;](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/June05Eye.pdf) treat it as a singular pronoun for any coreferential needs.

Comment: What is an articulated sentence?

Comment: Maybe it's not the most proper term, I mean a long sentence made of many prepositions connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

> If {a person / someone} lies to you like this, they are probably a thief. [Singular subject]
>
> If people lie to you like this, they're probably thieves. [Plural subject]